# Mysql fulltext index in multicolumn & "AND operator"

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table `match'(id, white, black, event)`. I would like to find all rows which has "first" word in column white, "second" word in column black and "third" word in column event.

I can do this easy by "like" operator as following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `match` 
WHERE 
  white like '%first%' 
  AND black like '%second%' 
  AND event like '%third%'
```

However my table contains about 10 million rows. How can I apply fullindex search?

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure you have the table created with the default engine as myisam and do a alter table table_name add fulltext (column)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend a LIKE wildcard search over a table with as many row it would slow the query down significantly